# CSS queries for different pixel widths are not applied

Tags: css, media-queries, pixel

I am facing an issue in having my CSS applied on certain widths.
What I am trying to achieve is the following:
Initially I have the following styling:

```
:root { --main-bg-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);}
```

this will be my main background color, what I try to do later is the following:

```
@media screen and (width: 782px){ :root { --main-bg-color: rgb(128, 128, 0); } }
@media screen and (width: 783px){ :root { --main-bg-color: rgb(128, 0, 128); } }
@media screen and (width: 784px){ :root { --main-bg-color: rgb(65, 99, 0); } }
....
@media screen and (width: 882px){ :root { --main-bg-color: rgb(0, 128, 99); } }
@media screen and (width: 883px){ :root { --main-bg-color: rgb(99, 33, 99); } }
@media screen and (width: 884px){ :root { --main-bg-color: rgb(56, 188, 35); } }
```

The issue is that some widths are not being applied. I read about the issue and what I understood was that the issue might be because of different definition between pixels in css and the actual pixels in screen.

What I want to eventually do is when I change the width of my view-port to be able to match the color in my CSS with the width that shows in the browser developer tools

I added a jsfiddle sample, but what is weird is that on jsfiddle the media queries don't work at all while on my own project some of the media queries work:

https://jsfiddle.net/SooSoo_El_Shreer/djpnbg9s/3/

Comment: use `@media screen and (max-width: [value]px){ ... }` or `@media screen and (min-width: [value]px){ ... }` depending on when you want your styles applied.

Comment: starting with bigger screens and using max-width in media queries is a more "natural and easy" thought process when it comes to HTML and CSS, but starting with small screens and working your way up using min-width in media queries is considered best practice (also forces/promotes the use of responsive as opposed to adaptive design style).

Comment: @Martin I don't understand why do you want me to use min-width and max-width. What am trying to achieve is to have different color on different pixel widths. I am not trying to apply a range. So for example on pixel 333 I want green, pixel 334 I want red, pixel 335 blue and so on

Comment: Yes, it's known that you will sometimes encounter rendering issues when targeting EXACT pixels outside of known device ranges. A workaround would be to combine the max-width and min-width. At least that's the way to do it for now... Example: `@media screen and (min-width: 782px) and (max-width: 982px) { ... }`. Let me know if this fixes your issues. Tedious, I know...

Comment: @Martin  No it didn't fix the problem for me. Currently I am trying to target pixels from a range of 285 till 1400 pixels. I want for each one of those points to have a different color. Currently for example the pixels 777-779 don't match the rules in my CSS. They are supposed to be of certain colors, yet they fall back to the original color declared at the start: :root { --main-bg-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);}